DC Josepshon current calculation using Furusaki-Tsukada Formula
I am working on calculating the current in a Superconductor/Insulator/Ferromagnet/Insulator/Superconductor (SIFIS) junction using the Furusaki-Tsukada formula (https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0305437), which relates the current to Andreev reflection scattering amplitudes and uses the imaginary time Green's function for the calculation. Specifically, I am following these general steps:

Wave Function Information: I obtain the wave function information from the Bogoliubov–de Gennes equation.
Scattering Amplitudes: I compute the Andreev reflection scattering amplitudes by matching the boundary condition of the wave function.
Analytic Continuation: I perform the analytic continuation from real energy ( E ) to imaginary frequency $i\omega_n$, where $i\omega_n$ is the Matsubara frequency.
Current Calculation: Finally, I use the scattering amplitudes ($a_1$ and $a_2$) at ( E = $i\omega_n$) to compute the current (I) and then sum over all the Matsubara frequencies. Where the current is given by

$$ I = I_0 \sum_{\omega_n} \frac{(k_{n}^+ + k_{n}^-)}{\sqrt{\omega_n^2 + \Delta^2}}\left(\frac{a_1(i\omega_n)}{k_{n}^+} - \frac{a_2(i\omega_n)}{k_{n}^-}\right)$$
However, I am encountering a discrepancy between my numerical results and the existing analytical results (https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0305437) for the current in the SIFIS junction. The current I calculate does not match well with the expected outcomes.
I suspect the issue might be related to the analytic continuation process. Specifically, I compute the values of the parameters $a_1$ and $a_2$ at ($E = i\omega_n$) and use these values in the current calculation, but it seems that something is going wrong during this step.
Has anyone encountered similar issues while performing this type of calculation, or does anyone have advice on correctly performing the analytic continuation for these systems? Any insights on possible mistakes or tips for ensuring the correct numerical treatment of the analytic continuation would be greatly appreciated!
